# How can I lookup a named url in a view?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to fill out the `success_url` of a django form view using a named url:

```
class RegisterView(generic.edit.FormView):
    template_name = "cmmods/register.html"
    form_class = RegisterForm
    #success_url = reverse('complete-registration')
    success_url = "/cmmods/complete-registration"
```

When I type the URL explicitly, as uncommented above, it works.

When I try to do a reverse lookup of the url (currently commented out, above) , I get:

> The included urlconf 'cm_central.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

I guess it's clear that my urls.py is actually valid (does have patterns in it), since the uncommented version of the code works.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That means the dependency has not been loaded yet. You can use `reverse_lazy` to defer the evaluation of the url pattern

Like this:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('complete-registration')
```

Documentation of [`reverse_lazy` can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)